# C# How do I run some code for the selected item in a listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox of names, I want to click one of the names so that it is highlighted and then click a button that runs some code for the selected item. How do I call this selected item?

```
    private void btnEcho_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         listbox1.SelectedItem......
    }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The listbox isn't very intuitive because it contains objects instead of something like ListItem, but if you just want the text you can do this:

```
string selectedText = listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: Don't forget the null check. What if nothing is selected? Or your list contains no items?

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = listbox1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

Don't forget to do a null check, because this will throw an error if your list is empty or if no value is selected.

Comment: if this is a web project, you can leave off the ToString() as the Value property is a string already.

Comment: ah, it looks like the "listbox" should have clued me in that it's not an aspnet project. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

`Listbox1.SelectedItem` gets the actual selected item. You can then further call from **SelectedItem** to get other properties/methods such as `SelectedItem.Text` or `SelectedItem.Value`

If you wanted to make it all happen upon selection from the listbox (instead of pressing a button), you could just add a `SelectedIndexChanged` event for Listbox1 (and in ASP.NET make sure that `AutoPostBack` is set to TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = listbox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

here you have the what value(name) selected.

```
if(str == null || str == string.empty) return;
```

and so on. you can do whatever you want; 
goodluck

Answer (score -1):

You're question is not clearly to me.

Example, you have a listbox of three items: A, B and C.
You have, as you do with your example, a click-event. In that click-event you can use the switch-statement to handle some code for each item:

```
switch (listbox1.SelectedItem)
{
  case "A":
       // Code when select A
       break;
  case "B":
       // Code when select B
       break;
  ... (and so on).
}
```

Code is an example and not tested. See switch for more information.